# Divergent serie

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show the convergence or divergence of the serie $\sum _{ n\ge 1 }^{  }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ \left( n+1 \right) ! } \prod _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ f\left( k \right)  }  \right)  } $, where $f:\mathbb{N}-\left\{ 0 \right\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}-\left\{ 0 \right\} $ injective function. I do not see how to apply the various convergence test that exist to the given problem.Thanks for the help.

Comment: This just begs the ratio test, now doesn't it?

Comment: Hint:
$$\prod_{k=1}^nf(k)\ge n!$$
The rest is a direct comparison test.

Comment: Now on the other hand, what have you tried?  It helps everyone to know where you are at on the problem, and it is generally recommended.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's a great observation, but the OP might need some guidance as to how to see/prove it.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, though its hard to know what guidance the OP needs if they a) don't include any context so that I may judge how much help they need and b) don't respond to comments :-/ ...

Comment: Though I suppose one might argue the OP already knows the answer, as per the title?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's definitely fair, and if OP doesn't ask for further clarification I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

The Pigeon-Hole Principle : If $n+1$ or more pigeons fly into $n$ pigeon-holes (with $n\geq 1),$ then at least one pigeon-hole will have at least $2$ pigeons in it.

For $n\geq 1$ let $S(n)$ be the sentence: If $T$ is a set of $n$ distinct positive integers then $\prod_{t\in T}t\geq n!.$

Obviously $S(1)$ is true.

Suppose $S(n)$ is true. Let $T'$ be a set of $n+1$ distinct positive integers. Then $\max T'\geq n+1,$ otherwise $T'\subset \{1,...,n\}$ which by the Pigeon-Hole Principle would imply that at least two distinct members of $T'$ are the same, which is absurd. Now $T=T'$ \ $\{\max T'\}$ is a set  of $n$ distinct positive integers, so by $S(n)$ we have $ \prod_{t\in T'}t'=\max (T')\cdot \prod_{t\in T}t\geq (n+1)\cdot n!=(n+1)!.$ So $S(n)\implies S(n+1).$

By induction $S(n)$ is true for every $n.$ Hence $\prod_{j=1}^nf(j)\geq n!$ for every $n.$